# Increasing Engagement on a new Gaming Blog

Tags: small-communities, user-engagement, blog

I recently started a new gaming blog and wanted to get opinions on the best way to build my audience and increase the engagement of the community I already have. I've already set up a website using Wordpress and have the Facebook and Twitter pages too.

The visuals are not 100% done yet but I am currently working on it. I have managed to gather around 70 Facebook followers and am getting some slow traffic through the website. Each time I post a blog entry I post a link onto the Facebook and Twitter (connected).

So far I have done a few posts but the only real way to get any reach has been to pay for Facebook's advertising which seems to only get a few results.

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

G

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, step back, and think about some questions.

- What is the special thing about my blog?
- Can I solely handle the gaming blog?
- Am I up to partnerships, or ads?
- Can I do some cross publishing, or [transmedia storytelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmedia_storytelling)?

**What is so special about my blog?**

What is the thing that makes you outstanding? Is it the good system of keeping up discussions, or your exclusive content? Maybe, you have the option to let users write their reviews. Or users can up- or downvote your articles. Is it your monthly / weekly / daily newsletter containing the latest stuff about the gaming world? Or is it the cool giveaway you do in a regular manner? Point out your special thing that most other gaming blogs lack. People won't come to you if you are as normal as everyone else.

**Can I solely handle the gaming blog?**

That's linked with your motivation. Can you keep up a news feed everyday? Can you provide special content, e.g. ratings, indie games? Can you keep up with the growth of your community and still provide the necessary social actions you are asked for? This includes replying to emails in time, or discussing with your readers. If you can't keep on track with your users, you will most likely lose the grip, and fall in a deep hole of hatred and flame.

**Am I up to partnerships, or ads?**

You have a gaming blog at its beginning. So how about doing some partnerships with blogs experiencing the same problems? With that in mind, you can easily "exchange" users and get access to a bigger audience. Maybe you want to advertise your blog.

**Can I do some cross publishing, or transmedia storytelling?**

If you want to grow, you must be accessible. Everywhere, every time, whenever the user likes to. Make sure that you have a mobile app or version of your site to meet the demands of your audience. Think about publishing articles on your website and on your social media sites. You could do a little summary of your lengthy review and post it on Facebook, and link it to your original article then. Don't just post the link. If you reached a critical mass, you can advertise in magazines, a little logo showing your badass blog.

**In the beginning...**

...it's all about being active and a *regular contributor*. You won't be successful in a day, not in a month either. You have to be patient. Wait it, be nice to your community, build up opportunities for them so they can participate, too. Don't overdo it, treat your little audience as something really important. If you value your community, they will give it back to you by sharing your blog on social media sites or in real life.